# Generating time series data in Java/Python

Tags: java, python, apache, pandas, math

I want to generate time series data in a such a way that the data spikes at the start of the month.

I am using the apache math libraries to generate the data that generates uniform real distribution. I have parameterized the average and standard deviation values.

```
RealDistribution distribution = getDistribution(
                                UNIFORM_REAL_DISTRIBUTION, average, deviation);
```

I have an issue where the data generation is not deterministic. i.e I want the peak value to be generated exactly at the same time of the day every month. But
with this approach, it is getting generated at a random time.

Would appreciate if you can share pointers on generating time series data for a month with spike happening on the 'n' th hour every month.